# website slideshow - how to protect images from download?

Tags: html, image, web

we have website with slideshow control which display a set of images. Client requested to "protect" them from downloading. I know about simple ways to do this:

1. Disable right click
2. Put transparent overlay on top of the real image
3. Use CSS background
4. Use canvas
5. Watermarking
6. etc...

all of these are only for "casual" users - those ones who are not aware of Dev Tools in chrome.

Are there other ways to "protect" images? The only approach I could think of is to develop custom flash (or silverlight) plugin which will send image ID to the webserver and receive "encoded" byte stream - and decode it and display it. Am I over-complicating this? are there other ways to prevent image download?

if flash plugin + webservice approach is the right way to go - are there any ready-to-go solutions, or I should develop everything from scratch?

Thank you.

Comment: If your goal is to let the user see the image, there is no way to prevent them from downloading it. They can simply take a screenshot of their browser, and bypass all of the effort you've put into stopping them.

Answer (score 4):

THere's no way to protect your image against being downloaded. Your users have to download it to view it. Your proprietary player will fail too if someone uses screen capture tools.

EDIT:
The best thing you can to is to make the reuse (I assume you don't want your visitors to use it elsewhere?) of the image as difficult as possible. Watermarks might be a good start to deter some people because they don't have the resource and expertise to de-watermark. Or you can embed steganography as a proof of origin so you can sue them afterward. Again, it's all about trade off between cost to do this and benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to prevent people from downloading your images. But, I want to offer another perspective -- you can create images that people like to view and play with but don't ***necessarily*** want to download.

Here's an example:

[xkcd: Click and Drag](http://xkcd.com/1110/)

Answer (score 0):

If the images have an intrinsic value that the client wants to protect, yet has to allow potential purchasers to view prior to purchase, then you need to minimize the value of the pre-purchase image.  Only displaying thumbnails, adding visible watermarks, and otherwise distorting the image in ways that humans can easily see *past*, but will still *see* are usual here.

Then there is the issue of protecting the post-purchase images.  Invisible watermarking (one example [here](http://www.adptools.com/en/signmyimage-description.html), another [here](https://www.digimarc.com/digimarc-for-images)) can allow the customer to purchase and use the image as you allow, but if the image appears somewhere, used in an inappropriate manner, you can use the ID embedded invisibly (to a human) to identify just which customer violated the Terms of Use.  These watermarks may even survive a degree of image manipulation and even digital photography of the image on a monitor.

If any user of the site has to be able to view the full, un-devalued image, you could add an unique ID linked to their IP address to the image as it is delivered to the slideshow control, so that each user receives a unique "copy", and you can trace misuse of an image to an IP address (and date, as many users have dynamic IPs, but ISPs keep records of IP assignments over time) for potential prosecution.